# IIS web.config Negative Lookahead Redirect Not Working

Tags: regex, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I am trying to match all urls in web.config that don't contain the string "scadmin1" but do contain "/admin".

According to RegexPal (a website), the following Regex should work:

```
^(?:(?!\.scadmin1).)*/admin$?
```

It isn't working in the web.config file however.  Here's my complete rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="RedirectAllAdminRequestsToAdminArea">
      <match url="^(?:(?!\.scadmin1).)*/admin$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://scadmin1.myurl.com/admin"
          appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure it's not choking on those \r and \n? Perhaps they need to be \\r and \\n? (just a guess; never used IIS).

Comment: Try the following perhaps. `^(?:(?!scadmin1).)*\/admin`

Comment: hwnd no luck with that unfortunately. Zoffix it doesn't work without the \r\n either. I don't think they serve a particular purpose in this example or our use case so I will remove that from the code now.